# Azure Template validation failure , expression is not valid

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

I've exported a resource group that contains some Logic apps that I want to use in Visual Studio but one Logic App is unable to be opened using the designer-view in VS.

I get this error even thou I haven’t modified the code in any way:

> The template validation failed: 'The property 'expression' '[concat('@equals(toLower(triggerBody()?['', parameters('workflows_Booking_name'),'s']?['Event']), 'create')')]'
>   of template action 'Condition_-_Create_or_UpdateBookings' at line '1' and column '1827' is not a valid template language expression.'.

This is what the Logic App looks like in the portal for better understanding.
[image]

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the template itself. If you look carefully at the error message, the expressions contains [concat('...')] which looks like an ARM template expression, not a logic app definition expression. Can you take a look in code-view and confirm that this is the case (and confirm with the original Logic App whether it is the same)?

Comment: Can you share the template?

Answer (score 0):

As Szymon Wylezol  mentioned that it seems that it is wrong with the template itself. From the error message we know that expression `[concat('@equals(toLower(triggerBody()?['', parameters('workflows_Booking_name'),'s']?['Event']), 'create')')]` is incorrect. More detail about expressions please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#expressions).

According to your supplied screenshot that we can get the expression as following in the code view:

```
"actions": {
    "Condition_-_Create_or_UpdateBookings": {
      "type": "If",
      "expression": "@equals(toLower(triggerBody()?['Bookings']?['Event']), 'create')",
      "actions": {},
      "runAfter": {}
    }
  }
```

Please compare the code view in the VS with code view in the Azure portal.

[image]

[image]

Then it should be ready for view in the Visual Studio. More details about **Design, build, and deploy Azure Logic Apps in Visual Studio** please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-deploy-from-vs)

[image]

Demo code.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workflows_testlogic_name": {
            "defaultValue": "testlogic",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "workflows_tomtestLogicApp_name": {
            "defaultValue": "tomtestLogicApp",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/ed0caab7-c6d4-45e9-9289-c7e5997c9241/resourceGroups/tomtestlogicApp/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/testlogic'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_testlogic_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "location": "eastasia",
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "triggers": {
                        "manual": {
                            "type": "Request",
                            "kind": "Http",
                            "inputs": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "properties": {
                                      "event": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "value": ""
                                      },
                                        "name": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "value": ""
                                        },
                                        "participants": {
                                            "type": "integer",
                                            "value": ""
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "Condition": {
                            "actions": {},
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "expression": "@equals(toLower(triggerBody()?['name']), 'test')",
                            "type": "If"
                        }
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {}
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/ed0caab7-c6d4-45e9-9289-c7e5997c9241/resourceGroups/tomtestlogicApp/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/tomtestLogicApp'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_tomtestLogicApp_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "location": "eastasia",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "LogicApp"
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "triggers": {
                        "manual": {
                            "type": "Request",
                            "kind": "Http",
                            "inputs": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "Bookings": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "BookedByEmail": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "Event": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "Condition_-_Create_or_UpdateBookings": {
                            "actions": {},
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "expression": "@equals(toLower(triggerBody()?['Bookings']?['Event']), 'create')",
                            "type": "If"
                        }
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {}
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ]
}
```